# Python: Protocol requiring class property

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

My method requires an object with the attribute `pattern` and the function `handle`. To this end, I wrote a `Protocol` instance with these two members. Consider the following code:

```
class Handler(typing.Protocol):
    """Handler protocol"""

    pattern: re.Pattern

    @staticmethod
    def handle(match: re.Match) -> str:
        pass


def f(obj: Handler, text: str):
    output = []
    for match in re.finditer(obj.pattern, text):
        output.append(obj.handle(match))
    return output


class MyHandler(Handler):
    pattern = re.compile("hello world")

    @staticmethod
    def handle(match: re.Match) -> str:
        return "hi there"


f(MyHandler, 'hello world, what a nice morning!')
```

However, when I call this function with `MyHandler`, my IDE (PyCharm) issues the following warning:

> Expected type 'ReplacerProtocol', got 'Type[CitationReplacer]' instead

This warning goes away when I remove the `pattern` attribute from the protocol class. When I change the protocol to require a `@property` or a function with the name `pattern`, the same warning is issued.

What is the correct way to define my interface in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per suggested by Sterliakov, I made edits to my code. I removed the use of @property in the implementation of MyHandler as it was deemed unnecessary for the protocol. Additionally, I incorporated generics (re.Pattern[str] and re.Match[str]) as advised.

```
import typing

class Handler(typing.Protocol):
    """Handler protocol"""

    pattern: re.Pattern[str]

    @staticmethod
    def handle(match: re.Match[str]) -> str:
        ...


def f(obj: Handler, text: str) -> list[str]:
    output = []
    for match in re.finditer(obj.pattern, text):
        output.append(obj.handle(match))
    return output


class MyHandler:
    pattern: re.Pattern[str] = re.compile("hello world")

    @staticmethod
    def handle(match: re.Match[str]) -> str:
        return "hi there"


result = f(MyHandler(), 'hello world, what a nice morning!')
print(result)
```

Comment: No need to make it a `property` in the implementation, this answer represents some misconception about `property` meaning in Protocol. Plain class/instance attr is fine against protocol's `property`: it just indicates that attribute must exist and should be at least readable (not necessary settable), as opposed to `pattern: re.Pattern` requirement which is settable. Finally, `re.{Pattern,Match}` are generic and represent underlying type (str or bytes) - omitting generics here is not a wise choice. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=740fbe0b85d95a98643a8f3409a147ae

Comment: @Sterliakov, This is agood suggestion, Thank you, I am learning, so mistakes happend, I corrected in my  in second answer

Comment: Please [edit] instead to provide corrections to existing q/a - second answer is only a way to provide a drastically different solution so that they are voted on separately.